# Simplifying error handling in Rust, in case of Result<Option<T>>

Tags: rust

Just imagine I have a function with `Result<Option<T>>` result.

If the `Result` is `Err` or `Option` is `None`, I want to return `MyError` error.

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to use pattern matching:

```
fn my_fun() -> Result<T, MyError> {
    if let Ok(Some(thing)) = other_fun() {
         Ok(thing)
    } else {
         Err(MyError{})
    }
}
```

or

```
fn my_fun() -> Result<T, MyError> {
    match other_fun() {
        Ok(Some(thing)) => Ok(thing),
        _ => Err(MyError{}),
    }
}
```

If your error implements `From<TheOtherError>`, which is probably a good idea here, you can also do

```
fn my_fun() -> Result<T, MyError> {
    other_fun()?.ok_or(MyError{})
}
```

Comment: Seems like a great place for [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/book/if-let.html).

Comment: @YannVernier you're right (in fact the if let solution is quite longer and maybe not more readable but I know it's the solution that clippy favors anyway so let's go for it)

Comment: That's exactly the way I get to:

let t = match result_option_t {
    Ok(Some(t)) => t,
    _ => return Err(MyError),
};

Answer (score 1):

There are also other useful functions in Option and Result to help you do this.

```
fn other_function() -> Result<Option<T>, OtherErr> {
   ...
}

fn call_other() -> Result<T, MyError> {
    other_function()
        // starting with a Result<Option<T>, OtherErr>
        .map_err(|other_err|  make MyError from other_err)
        // now it's a Result<Option<T>, MyError>
        .and_then(|opt_t| opt_t.ok_or_else(|| make MyError for None))
        // now it's a Result<T, MyError>
}
```